# Apply CSS to div according to screen orientation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a div to have a different height when the screen is either landscape or portrait. I would use media query but not sure if that auto resizes the div if the device is rotated in hand.

I have this so far but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #header {
    position:relative;
    height:100vh;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > $(this).width() {
      $('#header').css("height","50vh"); }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: use media queries instead

Comment: use `)` after function end

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    // styles
}
```

landscape can be changed with portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start messing around with JQuery to style your elements, maybe take a deeper look into CSS media queries:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation

Answer (score 0):

You could use landscape and portrait orientation in media queries and can acheive this.

Some things like this.

```css
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  #header {
    position: relative;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  #header {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
</header>
```

Comment: Will this media query auto update when the device is rotated? Or will the page have to be reloaded?

Comment: It should. It all about width vs height comparision. You could find more about orientation here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation . So when you even resize the code snippet window, you should be able to see it in action